# Generating a report by taking data from multiple databases

Tags: jasper-reports

I am wondering is there a way to get data from more than one database and merge the data to a single report.

For example, lets consider there are two databases *DB1* and *DB2* with table *t1* and *t2* respectively.
The *t1* has a column *c1* which is same as *c1* in *t2*.

Now I have to fetch *c1* from *t1* and need to see is there any data for *c1* in *t2*. If so get the data from both *t1* and *t2* and display it as single report.

This I want in *JasperReports*. Will *JR* support this? If so how?

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give the problem of fetching data from different databases in the java side (not in the jasperreport). You can create a list of POJOs containing the data fetched from different databases then pass that list to the jasperreport.